# A member of the type, 'Column1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

How can I call a stored procedure from a Web API controller?

I have the following code to get data from the SQL Server database using Web API, I have api which working fine, but I wanted to use stored procedures instead.

The stored procedure name is `uspStaffDirectoryGetAllXXXEmployeeInfo`, I imported it into the `.edmx` as `GetEmployeeInformation`.
 
Note: the stored procedure contains fields from another database.

Here is my code which is working for me but I want to replace it using stored procedures.

```
private EmployeesEntities db = new EmployeesEntities();

public IHttpActionResult GetEmployees()
{
    var query = (from emp in db.employees  
                 select new
                        {
                            emp.employee_number,
                            emp.employee_photo,
                            emp.first_name,
                            emp.last_name,
                        });
     
     var employees = query.ToList();
     
     return Ok(employees);
}
```

Here Is the code I used to get data using the stored procedure `uspStaffDirectoryGetAllXXXXEmployeeInfo`:

```
private EmployeesEntities db = new EmployeesEntities();
     
//[HttpGet]
public List<uspStaffDirectoryGetAllXXXXEmployeeInfo_Result> Get()
{
    List<uspStaffDirectoryGetAllXXXXEmployeeInfo_Result> emplist = new List<uspStaffDirectoryGetAllXXXXEmployeeInfo_Result>();

    using (EmployeesEntities db = new EmployeesEntities())
    {
        var results = db.uspStaffDirectoryGetAllXXXXEmployeeInfo();

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            var employee = new uspStaffDirectoryGetAllXXXXEmployeeInfo_Result()
                                      {
                                          id = result.id,
                                          Employee_Display_Name = result.Employee_Display_Name,
                                          first_name = result.first_name,
                                          last_name = result.last_name,
                                          Employee_Phone = result.Employee_Phone,
                                          Employee_Email = result.Employee_Email
                                      };
        emplist.Add(employee);
    }

    return emplist;
}
```

But when I run the API I keep getting this error, I don’t have a field called 'Column1' anywhere

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'EmployeesModel.uspStaffDirectoryGetAllXXXXEmployeeInfo_Result'. A member of the type, 'Column1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'

On this line

```
public virtual ObjectResult<uspStaffDirectoryGetAllXXXEmployeeInfo_Result> uspStaffDirectoryGetAllXXXXEmployeeInfo()
{
     return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<uspStaffDirectoryGetAllXXXXEmployeeInfo_Result>("uspStaffDirectoryGetAllXXXXEmployeeInfo");
}
```

What did I miss? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a named or calculated name column that is returned by the stored procedure ?

In this case you have to give it a name :

ex `select "my value" as "colName"`